# infinispan invalidation cache and MarshallingException: ISPN000615

Tags: caching, wildfly, infinispan, jgroups

In our application, we cache data in an local infinispan cache. The cached data is loaded from the database.

Now we are making adjustments for running in a clustered environment using Wildfly (25.0.1-Final and default infinispan included with Wildfly).

The communication stack (tcp/jgroups/tcp_ping) is working and the nodes see each other. The normal caches are updated correctly with all nodes:

```
  my-cluster-1    | 17:38:03,599 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-9,ejb,my-cluster-1) 
 [Context=my.ear/web.war#my.my.core.model.i18n.Language] 
 ISPN100008: Updating cache members list [my-cluster-1, my-cluster-2], topology id 3
 my-cluster-1    | 17:38:03,627 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-9,ejb,my-cluster-1) 
 [Context=my.ear/web.war#my.my.core.model.base.ComplexEntity.collectionToCEs] 
 ISPN100008: Updating cache members list [my-cluster-1, my-cluster-2], topology id 3
 my-cluster-1    | 17:38:03,664 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-9,ejb,my-cluster-1) 
 [Context=my.ear/web.war#my.my.core.model.base.ComplexTypeEntity] 
 ISPN100008: Updating cache members list [my-cluster-1, my-cluster-2], topology id 3
```

Now we want to change the infinispan local cache to an invalidation cache, to notify all nodes to refresh their cached data if data is changed on any node.

Based on the documentation:
https://dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-infinispan

> An invalidation cache is a special type of clustered cache that does not share any data: only invalidation messages are sent to other members in the cluster when a node modifies/removes an entry, thus avoiding stale data.

I understand that no data is shared, only invalidation messages are sent.

Here is our cache-container configuration in `standalone.xml`:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:13.0">
        <cache-container name="mc" marshaller="PROTOSTREAM">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
        </cache-container>
```

We are fetching the embedded cache manager as follows:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/container/mc") //
private EmbeddedCacheManager defaultCacheManager;
```

And using it with the cache builder to create the cache in our code (either locally or distributed as invalidation async):

```
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        if (dist) //different config for invalidation cache
            builder
                .clustering().cacheMode( CacheMode.INVALIDATION_ASYNC ) 
                .memory().storage( StorageType.HEAP)
                .encoding().mediaType("application/x-protostream");
        else //default, local cache
            builder
            .clustering().cacheMode( CacheMode.LOCAL);      
        defaultCacheManager.defineConfiguration( cacheName, builder.build());
```

Regarding the configurations in XML and cach builder: we added the PROTOSTREAM, encoding and memory settings today, after initial errors about marshaller, but they did not help.

When we start up the Wildlfy cluster we get this error `ISPN000615: Unable to unmarshall 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' as a marshaller is not present in the user or global SerializationContext"}}` in the server.log and the system fails to start:

```
my-cluster-2    |     Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: 
Unable to invoke protected void my.service.index.IndexConfig.init() on indexconfig
my-cluster-2    |     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
my-cluster-2    |     Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.marshall.MarshallingException:
ISPN000615: Unable to unmarshall 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' as a marshaller is not present 
in the user or global SerializationContext"}}
```

I understand that infinispan cannot unmarshall the linked hash map, but my understanding is that the cached data remains local and only invalidations are sent over the wire. The same settings worked with local cache before this change.  Is there any way to resolve this issue with invalidation caches short of writing our own marshaller?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question with feedback from my architect:

It doesn't matter if we enter a marshaller in the standalone.xml (which corresponds to the default "LEGACY" marshaller) or explicitly `<cache-container name="my-test-mgr" marshaller="JBOSS">`, I get in both cases as marshaller the wildfly impl. `org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling.jboss.JBossMarshaller`

This marshaller can automatically handle serializable Java classes (including Map, List...), but it actually doesn't allow a put of a non-serializable object, even if it's just an invalidation cache, and the object doesn't need to be serialized at all. All distributed caches seem to force this behavior.

In a forum I found a hint that you should wrap entries in the cache in a CacheEntry class ... Wildfly does the same internally. I tried this, and then the put works... BUT.. after put and get again, the value in the entry is "null" (in our case the cached entity is gone), so the cache is pointless.

OK... Magic. If you define the cache like this, then everything works as expected - even with non-serializable objects:

```
manager.defineConfiguration( cacheName, 
 new ConfigurationBuilder()
.clustering().cacheMode( CacheMode.INVALIDATION_ASYNC)
.encoding().mediaType( "application/x-java-object").build());
```

So instead of "application/x-protostream", we used   "application/x-java-object" and it just worked.

Comment: For future reference, media type `application/x-java-object` means the values are stored in memory and are never serialized. Any other (supported) media type requires serialization, not just for clustered caches, but for local caches as well.